# How can I move a node type's configuration into a custom module?

Tags: 8, configuration

I still a bit new to D8 and loving the new configuration management system that has replaced Features.

I am looking for the best technique for containing particular configurations in my custom modules.

I have a node type called **quiz** and a module called **quiz_module**. By default, when I execute **drush cex -y** the output yaml files are deposited into **../config/sync**.

**Is it the correct thing to do to move all the yaml files relating to the quiz node type in to my quiz_module?** When do that, the same files are recreated whenever I execute *drush cex -y*.

To counter that duplication, I created a softlink of the files from *quiz_module* to '*../config/sync*' but that didn't seem to update the yaml files as I expected.

Any help, please?

Comment: Is this so that when you install the module on another site it would create your content types/fields? If so take a look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/include-default-configuration-in-your-drupal-8-module But if you're trying to just move part of the config export/import into multiple folders then you can't really. It all needs to be together in your specified sync folder

Comment: @Leigh: Yes, both your points. I had already read the article you suggested. However, according to what you said, it sounds like a D8 project needs to version control the entire sync directory and also have a separate git repo for the custom modules directory? I could be mistaken but there's almost no reason to create custom modules.

Comment: This isn't quite true. You can use the [Config Split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) to split configuration into multiple directories, but I don't think that's really what you'd want here. There's still a reason to create custom modules, they're just no longer the way you should deploy your configuration for a site.

Comment: You can use my answer from this post, I had the same “problem”, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/284865/72672.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration Management did not replace Features completely, Features still has its place.

My understanding is that:

- Configuration Management should be used to manage your configuration for a specific site/project.
- [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) should be used to export configuration to custom modules as you develop them *if* they're going to be re-used on another site.

The configuration in your custom module goes into 2 directories (install or optional).

- Configuration in the install directory is considered required and only gets imported when your module is installed.
- Configuration in the optional directory is optional and will import during your module install if all the dependencies are present. (I think it also gets imported if all dependencies are later installed.) E.g. If you define a View in your module's optional directory, that configuration would be installed *only* in two instances: 1. when you install your module, if Views is installed, or 2. when Views is installed later, sometime after your module is installed.

The [Features module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) lists several additional resources to help understand the differences between Configuration Management and Features.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to move a content type into a custom module is from the command line:

```
drupal config:export:content:type page \
  --module="demo" \
  --optional-config \
  --remove-uuid \
  --remove-config-hash
```

Source: https://drupalconsole.com/docs/en/commands/config-export-content-type