# Issue using Config Split on content types

Tags: 8, configuration

I'm working on setting up Config Split to share content type config between a number of multisites. Currently each site has its own config for various content types but, since they should be identical across all sites, I'd like to use Config Split to make it easier to manage.

I've configured Config Split with just just split off all config related to a content type with: `node.type.mycontenttype`. This works fine an all config is split out.

When I try to import it into one of the other sites it first tries to delete all existing config before importing the split. This causes it to fail since entities of that type already exist.

Is there a way around this or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Config split ignore dependencies](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/284865/config-split-ignore-dependencies)

Comment: Really, use Features for that. Use it to sync the content type to multiple multi-site instances and then export each instance's config as usual. Feature just being the development helper to locally sync a feature during development.

Comment: You should be able to split your content types just fine, could you provide a little bit more details by adding your content type's related config files? Might it be that the `uuid` is different in your splits, as that could indicate the import to see these as a different content types triggering the deletion.